# How to put an image in the center of a view?

Tags: swift, image, view, background

i have a view, I want to put a background, but the background should be center. but when the app run the background isn't center

this is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var ballView: SpringView!
```

ballView is a UIView custom, it isn't a imageview

in the viewdidload

```
ballView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "mujer.jpg")!)
ballView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
```

this is the app running, I tried with scale to fill but isn't works

[image not center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUCE8.jpg)
[this is the bacground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRUes.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like to use **UIImageView** as a subview, you can try to set background in view's **layer** like the following code.

```
 let image =  UIImage(named: "mujer.jpg")
 ballView.layer.contents = image?.cgImage
 ballView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
```

Comment: thanks Razib, your code lines its helped me very much

Comment: @AndresGomez , its my pleasure,  please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So create horizontal and vertical constraints that make the image view's center be equal to the parent view's center. (You can set up these constraints in your Storyboard)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm not seeing where there's a `UIImageView` involved. (I do agree that the easiest solution is to use a view hierarchy along with one.) I think the OP implies that `SpringView` is a custom `UIView`.

Comment: Maybe you're right. The question didn't provide a lot of detail, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add your code in viewDidAppear. When you use auto layout it uses the sizes from the storyboard device setting in viewDidLoad